# Warning during WebLogic server startup

Tags: session, weblogic, listener, weblogic-10.x

Whenever I start the WebLogic server I see the below warning in the console.

```
<Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101164> <User defined class com.org.listener.SessionTracking is not a Listener, as it does not implement the correct interface(s).>
```

SessionTracking.java

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SessionTracking implements Serializable, javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingListener{
//code
}
```

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.org.listener.SessionTracking</listener-class>
</listener>
```

How to resolve this?Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to specify the class in the web.xml.

> The Servlet 2.5 specification also contains the javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingListener and the javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionActivationListener interfaces. These interfaces are implemented by objects that are stored as session attributes and do not require registration of an event listener in web.xml.

[Application Events](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13712/app_events.htm)